# Integral of $2-$form on the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

Let $M$ be the torus $\Bbb{T}^2 = \Bbb{S}^1 \times \Bbb{S}^1 \subset \Bbb{R}^4$ by $\{(w,x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^4: w^2+x^2=y^2+z^2=1\}$. Let $\omega$ be the $2-$form

$$\omega = xyz\, dw \wedge dy.$$

Compute $\int_M \omega$.

**Attempt:**

The torus can be parameterized as a function $F:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^4$ defined via

$$(\phi,\theta) \mapsto(\cos \phi, \sin \phi, \cos \theta, \sin \theta).$$

So its enough to compute

$$\int_{[0,2\pi)^2}F^* \omega.$$

A quick computation shows $F^* \omega$ is

$$F^* \omega = \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta \cos \theta \, d \phi \wedge d \theta.$$

So we have

\begin{align}
\int_M F^* \omega&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta \cos \theta d \phi d \theta\\
&=0.
\end{align}

Is my solution correct? Also, this is exercise $16-2$ out of Lee's intro to smooth manifolds.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: I suppose you should also state that your parametrization is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, hence you can apply the relevant proposition in Lee.